# is it possible to apply smoothing effect to a function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am building scroll panel of images like jquery image gallery but only thumb icon part,
this is my code,,,

```
      function moveRight() {
        var imli = $(".thumbStrip li:first-child");
        $(".thumbStrip").append(imli);
    }
    function moveLeft() {
        var imli = $(".thumbStrip li:last-child");
        $(".thumbStrip").prepend(imli);         
    }
```

i want to apply smoothing effect while append or prepend,,
is it possible??
how?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
function moveRight() {
    $(".thumbStrip li:first-child").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(".thumbStrip").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

?

Or maybe:

```
function moveRight() {
    $(".thumbStrip li:first-child").animate({
        width: 'toggle',
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, function() {
        $(this).appendTo(".thumbStrip").animate({
            width: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'
        });
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/EyEPd/)